# Can't seem to find Natural Plugin in Eclipse Market place

Tags: java, eclipse, automation, bdd

I'm trying to install the Natural Plugin in Eclipse but I can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: A problem with a marketplace seems to be off topic for Stackoverlow.

Comment: @aled It's not _a_ marketplace, but _the_ marketplace for the Eclipse IDE and therefore clearly on-topic: [_"software tools commonly used by programmers"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Does installing it via _Help > Install New Software..._ and working with the update site [`https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural`](https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural) work? I guess the marketplace entry has been removed because of the HTTP instead of a HTTPS update site (at least on [GitHub](https://github.com/rlogiacco/Natural/#natural-installation-can-be-achieved-by-adding-the-natural-plugin-update-site-with-httprlogiaccogithubionatural-as-url) the `http://...` update site is mentioned).

Comment: Please see point 5: *"Questions asking for customer support with third-party services (such as App Stores) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, please direct your questions to the relevant company/organisation's technical support team."*

Comment: @aled The Eclipse Marketplace is not a third-party service or an App Store.

Comment: @howlger - It doesn't allow me to access the link which you gave. It throws 'Document could not be loaded by browser.'

Comment: Sure, it's an update site URL. In Eclipse got to _Help > Install New Software..._ and paste `https://rlogiacco.github.io/Natural` into the field _Work with_.